# Internet not working on my laptop (xps 9570) just at home, works fine on all other networks

Tags: network-manager, internet

Im having an issue with my internet. Two days ago after coming home from work, I noticed I can't connect to any site. Then I noticed that I have internet but it looks like I cant resolve DNS. I pinged 8.8.8.8 and had about 70% packet loss. Internet works fine on all other devices at home (iphone, android, mac, win 10 pc, google chrome). The internet on my laptop works fine on all other networks, including my mobile hotspot.

I called my isp and after trying to resolve the issue with them for two days they sent a technician to swap out my modem but I still have the same issue.

This started two days ago, prior to that it worked fine at home. Does anyone know what might be going on?

UPDATE: I installed MX Linux on a USB and I was able to browse the internet using the home network without a problem. I guess the issue lies in some configurations. I just can't understand why it works everywhere except at home.

UPDATE 2: I upgraded ubuntu to 19.10, but I still have the same problem. 
UPDATE 3: I noticed that when I first turn on my computer im able to browse the internet for ~30-40 seconds before I "lose" my connection. It will also randomly finish loading in pages after the internet stops working after 1-2 minutes, and then ill once again not have internet. Since the problem started last week I have been to many cafes with my laptop and the internet works everywhere, except on my home network. all other devices at home work fine.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using 18.04.3

Comment: Try this --> https://medium.com/@ahmadb/fixing-dns-issues-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bd4f9ca56620,

Comment: I added the alternate DNS, No luck, im starting to think that this is not a DNS issue. I might have thought it was one but sometimes times I connect sometimes I don't, so the issue might lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a dumb answer, but did you try using command `dhclient`? maybe it will repair the connection by rerefreshing your adapter config and apply dns trough dhcp again. seeing a laptop doesn't usually need fixed IP/DNS, why not use DHCP

Comment: no that did not seem to help, same behavior as before.